# open-uri is not redirecing http to https

Tags: ruby, rubygems, hpricot, open-uri

I am using Hpricot and OpenURI to parse webpages and extract URLs from them.

When I get a link like "http:rapidshare.com", it is not redirecting to https.
This is the error I got:

```
/home/leonidus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:216:in 
`open_loop': redirection forbidden: http:.................=>     
https:.........................
.
.
```

I tried to use the exception handler `OPENURI::HTTPREDIRECT` but then again I am getting the same error. I tried all the blogs but it is not resolved there also.

Comment: https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/open_uri_redirections.  patch packaged as a gem.

Comment: gem `open_uri_redirections` worked for me. Gracias Jaime!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [this Ruby bug report](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/859) for a discussion of why you're experiencing this issue. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1271420) for a monkey patch to OpenURI to allow "unsafe" redirects.

Comment: The bug's in the paperclip gem. Any idea if it was fixed at any version there?

Comment: "Updated by Yusuke Endoh over 1 year ago - Tracker changed from Bug to Feature"

Comment: This an old answer, but it's worth stating: The reason it's unsafe is that any and all requests over HTTP have the unlikely tinfoil but still technically-possible chance of being modified in-flight.  Patching code to allow unsafe redirects introduces a security issue, when the correct course is to use https:// always across any untrusted network and look at http:// with suspicion and privacy-diminishing implications.

Comment: Has paperclip fixed this issue? I'm experiencing it now